# Unable to access file from google cloud storage using endpoints API

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have created an endpoint API which is suppose to read from xml file stored on Google Cloud Storage.
But I am getting the following error:

> 503 Service Unavailable

Headers

```
{
 "error": {
  "message": "javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException\n - with linked 
exception:\n[java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService@3c11f7: 
No such file: GcsFilename(miceast1, Carpool.xml)]",
  "code": 503,
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException\n - with linked 
exception:\n[java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService@3c11f7: 
No such file: GcsFilename(miceast1, Carpool.xml)]"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

I am running the code in development sever.
Below is the code used to read from the file.

```
public CarPool receive() throws 
    Exception {
    CarPool carpool=new CarPool();
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(FocusAnything.class);
    Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

    GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
    GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename("miceast1", "Carpool.xml");

    GcsInputChannel readChannel = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        readChannel = gcsService.openReadChannel(filename, 0);
        reader = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(readChannel, "UTF8"));
        FocusAnything focus = (FocusAnything) um.unmarshal(reader);
        carpool = focus.getCarpool();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) { reader.close(); }
    }
    return carpool;
 }
```

Comment: Did you check whether the file exists in that bucket and with the exact letter casing. Also double check whether your application has access to the file.

Comment: Yes.. i did check for the casing. the names of bucket and file is given correctly. I have provided the app ID in ACL with Owner access.

Comment: So the 503 is in the response your own Endpoints API is returning on account of the FileNotFoundException. What you want to look at next are the application logs in the Developers Console for your App Engine backend (Operations -> Logging) to see if more details are there about the exception.

Comment: I tried deploying my project to app engine and its working.. :)  But its not working in development server. M getting the same exception

Comment: On the development server the GCS Client Library uses emulation using the local disk, so the issue is that the file isn't actually there locally - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/#Java_Using_the_client_library_with_the_development_app_server.